# How to display previous and next arrows in views

Tags: views

I am trying to create a views block that will display one item on a page. I like to display next and previous arrows but I see the next arrow by default and I do not see the previous arrow until I am on 2nd page. I can remove the numbers but how can I display only next and previous arrows by default?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There can only be a previous button if there are content before the current page. So logically there is no content before page 1. So obviously there will not be any previous page to go to.

Comment: I would like to have previous link to go to the last item. So, if I have 4 items and I am on the first page Prev will take them to 4th item.

Comment: You need to add the text "last >>" for last link. If you want the user to go back to the previous page they were on, the browser back button is for that purpose.

Comment: Maybe you need just a Carrousel?